# Python: PIL replace a single RGBA color

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library

I have already taken a look at this question: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616767/pil-best-way-to-replace-color) and seem to have implemented a very similar technique for replacing a single color including the alpha values:

```
c = Image.open(f)
c = c.convert("RGBA")
w, h = c.size
cnt = 0
for px in c.getdata():
    c.putpixel((int(cnt % w), int(cnt / w)), (255, 0, 0, px[3]))
    cnt += 1
```

However, this is very slow. I found [this recipe](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2002-December/002092.html) out on the interwebs, but have not had success using it thus far.

What I am trying to do is take various PNG images that consist of a single color, white.  Each pixel is 100% white with various alpha values, including alpha = 0.  What I want to do is basically colorize the image with a new set color, for instance #ff0000<00-ff>.  SO my starting and resulting images would look like this where the left side is my starting image and the right is my ending image (NOTE: background has been changed to a light gray so you can see it since it is actually transparent and you wouldn't be able to see the dots on the left.)

[image]

Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you have numpy, it provides a much, much faster way to operate on PIL images.

E.g.:

```
import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('test.png')
im = im.convert('RGBA')

data = np.array(im)   # "data" is a height x width x 4 numpy array
red, green, blue, alpha = data.T # Temporarily unpack the bands for readability

# Replace white with red... (leaves alpha values alone...)
white_areas = (red == 255) & (blue == 255) & (green == 255)
data[..., :-1][white_areas.T] = (255, 0, 0) # Transpose back needed

im2 = Image.fromarray(data)
im2.show()
```

Edit: It's a slow Monday, so I figured I'd add a couple of examples:

Just to show that it's leaving the alpha values alone, here's the results for a version of your example image with a radial gradient applied to the alpha channel:

Original: [image]

Result: [image]

Comment: Awesome! Awesome! Awesome!  +1 and marked as "Accepted."  Huge time saver and results are perfect.

Comment: shouldn't be , Red Green Blue ? white_areas =

Comment: data[..., :-1][white_areas] = (255, 0, 0)
IndexError: index 49 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 40

Comment: similar error here as Sekai :/

IndexError: index 200 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 200

Comment: @JoeKington can you please let us know how to solve this error: IndexError: index 1668 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1668 ?

Comment: It took me a minute to wrap my head around numpy, but it took my image processing (for example) from 0.58s to 0.18s.  I am more than impressed, and can't thank you enough for this one Joe.

Comment: The answer is some days old, but i really wanted to thank you for this!

Comment: Thank you... this saved me a ton of time!

Comment: I don't get the part `data[...`. What is that `...` supposed to mean?

Comment: Can someone explain why there are two transpose? red, green, blue, alpha = data.T # Temporarily unpack the bands for readability

# Replace white with red... (leaves alpha values alone...)
data[..., :-1][white_areas.T] = (255, 0, 0) # Transpose back needed  .

Answer (score 15):

Try this , in this sample we set the color to black if color is not white .

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PIL import Image
import sys

img = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
img = img.convert("RGBA")

pixdata = img.load()

# Clean the background noise, if color != white, then set to black.

for y in xrange(img.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(img.size[0]):
        if pixdata[x, y] == (255, 255, 255, 255):
            pixdata[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 255)
```

you can use color picker in gimp to absorb the color and see that's rgba color

Comment: on an image created by code instead of Image.open, that pixdata PixelAccess seems not working, i wonder why

Answer (score 5):

The Pythonware PIL online book chapter for the [Image module](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) stipulates that putpixel() is slow and suggests that it can be sped up by inlining. Or depending on PIL version, using load() instead.

Comment: The Provided Link is unactive now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match the color exactly (as the OP requested), you can set `FUZZINESS` to be a "tolerance threshold" below.
I used [@yuda-prawira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454229/yuda-prawira)'s answer as starter code but upgraded it to Python 3.

```
from PIL import Image
import sys

img = Image.open("./source-image.png")
COLOR_TO_DELETE = (70, 51, 46, 255)
FUZZINESS = 5

img = img.convert("RGBA")
pixdata = img.load()

for y in range(img.size[1]):
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        totalColorDiff = 0
        shouldReplace = True
        for idx in range(3): #include RGB but exclude alpha
            if abs(pixdata[x, y][idx] - COLOR_TO_DELETE[idx]) > FUZZINESS:
                shouldReplace = False
        
        if shouldReplace:
            pixdata[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 0) #replace with transparency
            
# Save the combined image
img.save('./bg-removed.png')
img.close()
```

It may be wise to compare neighboring pixels to prevent the algorithm from replacing in unwanted locations.