# Removing ALL colors except white in image in Python

Tags: python, image

Is there a way to remove ALL colors in the picture except white and subsequently replace the color white to black? Basically I want to remove the fuzz and I realised that only the color white is needed to decode the message.

Any help in python would be appreciated!

Original image:

[image: original]

---

Edited image:

[image: sample edited]

Comment: This question (asked by me 6 years ago) and the answers should provide a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752476/python-pil-replace-a-single-rgba-color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using `numpy` and `PIL`:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('pic.jpg')
data = np.array(img)

converted = np.where(data == 255, 0, 255)

img = Image.fromarray(converted.astype('uint8'))
img.save('new_pic.jpg')
```