# python pil colour fill

Tags: python, django, image, image-manipulation

I have a shape below: [image]

and I would like to colour only this shape, the background is transparent so I feel as if there is some way to colour an entire image. Right now I am using put pixel and colouring every pixel in the picture but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

`putpixel(xy=(i,j), value=(red))`, where i,j is coloured if it exists

Comment: Using this answer [Python: PIL replace a single RGBA color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752476/python-pil-replace-a-single-rgba-color) I was able to do it by changing 2 lines, the color the values in `grey_area = (red == 138) & (blue == 138) & (green == 138)` and `data[..., :-1][grey_area.T] = (255, 0, 0) # Transpose back needed` It produced this image https://i.imgur.com/OsqwhV6.png. I think it should also preserve the transparent background. The answer suggests to use "numpy, it provides a much, much faster way to operate on PIL images."

Comment: this was great it works perfectly, however it does not let me change the opacity of the colour by adding in an alpha value... Do you know what I would need to do to be able to change the opacity of the image

Comment: yes, if you define an opacity level of, say, `opacity_level = 50` then you could change the line to `data[..., :][grey_area.T] = (255, 0, 0, opacity_level)`. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I had to change a little more than that! I will post a solution below...

Answer (score 0):

Solution modified from:  [fill one colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752476/python-pil-replace-a-single-rgba-color)

Where these two lines were changed:

```
white_areas = (red == 138) & (blue == 138) & (green == 138) & (alpha == 255)
data[..., ][white_areas.T] = (25, 90, 0, 190)
```

previous solution:

```
white_areas = (red == 255) & (blue == 255) & (green == 255)
data[..., :-1][white_areas.T] = (255, 0, 0) # Transpose back needed
```

Removed :-1 from data

What these changes mean: also able to change opacity level