# Is there a way to transfer colors between similar images?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Can I take the colors of the image on the left and apply them to the image on the right?
For example - Replace the skin tone of the image on the right with that of the left (and do this for all parts of the image - hair, pants, etc).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0uIC.png)

Specifically looking for Python libraries to do this job but any tool in some other language also works.

I have checked Pillow but couldn't find an obvious solution there. I was also wondering that both these images might have numerous colors and hence it would be impossible to do this task.

Comment: Have you tried anything from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752476/python-pil-replace-a-single-rgba-color

Comment: @RolvApneseth I have looked at similar answers but my worry is that my image would contain many different colors and not just 3-4 that my human eye sees. And it becomes difficult to decide how to handle the many different colors that would emerge

Comment: My advice would be to make copies of the images and test out if it does what you want it to do, it can't cause any damage as long as you have backups