# How to get the bounding box of regions excluding specific RGB values

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am currently using `PIL.Image.Image.getbbox()` to get the bounding box for the non-zero (non-transparent) regions of an image.

What if I have an image that has a background of a specific color? How can I get the bounding box of the image then?  Same idea as `getbbox()` but instead of non-zero, I specify the RGB values.

Comment: [Replace that single color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3752476/11089932) accordingly (black, zero, transparent), and just run `getbbox()` on that image!?

Comment: No because this is color replacing. I want to get the bounding box of the non-(specific color) regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, my comment didn't properly express, what I wanted to suggest. So, here's a full answer:

- Make a copy of your image (that one, that has a specific background color).
- On that copy, replace the specific background color with black.
- Call `getbbox` on that copy.

Maybe, the following code and examples make things more clear:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Black background
img = Image.new('RGB', (400, 400), (0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.rectangle((40, 40, 160, 160), (255, 0, 0))
draw.rectangle((280, 260, 380, 330), (0, 255, 0))
img.save('black_bg.png')

print(img.getbbox(), '\n')

# Specific color background
bg_color = (255, 255, 0)
img = Image.new('RGB', (400, 400), bg_color)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.rectangle((40, 40, 160, 160), (255, 0, 0))
draw.rectangle((280, 260, 380, 330), (0, 255, 0))
img.save('color_bg.png')

print(img.getbbox(), '\n')

# Suggested color replacing (on image copy) - Pillow only, slow
img_copy = img.copy()
for y in range(img_copy.size[1]):
    for x in range(img_copy.size[0]):
        if img_copy.getpixel((x, y)) == bg_color:
            img_copy.putpixel((x, y), (0, 0, 0))

print(img_copy.getbbox(), '\n')

# Suggested color replacing (on image copy) - NumPy, fast
img_copy = np.array(img)
img_copy[np.all(img_copy == bg_color, axis=2), :] = 0

print(Image.fromarray(img_copy).getbbox())
```

There's one image with black background:

[image: Black background]

The corresponding output of `getbbox` is:

```
(40, 40, 381, 331)
```

Also, there's an image with a specific background color (yellow):

[image: Yellow background]

Calling `getbbox` on that image – obviously – returns:

```
(0, 0, 400, 400)
```

By simply replacing yellow with black in some copy of the second image, we again get the correct results from `getbbox` (both proposed methods):

```
(40, 40, 381, 331) 

(40, 40, 381, 331)
```

Since iterating single pixels in Pillow is kinda slow, you could also use NumPy's vectorization abilities to speed up that task.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
NumPy:         1.19.5
Pillow:        8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```