# GIMP's color to alpha in python

Tags: python, imshow

I would like to make the background of my `imshow` plots transparent. I know I can do this using the color to alpha option in GIMP. However, using GIMP in this case is not an option as I still need to perform actions after the background of `imshow` has been made transparent.

Is there a way to remove the background of `imshow` plots similar to GIMP's color to alpha in python without saving the figure first?

Comment: did you ever find a way of doing this?

Comment: so you just saved the figure, edited it in Gimp and then imported the image in Python?

Comment: This may be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1617909/1113207