# How do you create a new gif image in Python PIL

Tags: python

```
im = Image.new('P', (100,100), 'black')
```

All this does is return an error saying an integer is needed.  How do I create I gif image?  OR am I misunderstanding the 'P'.  I thought 'P' was to be used for gif images.  I'm wanting to be able to fill the image, pixel by pixel with preset colors(0-255) and not have the colors change when I go to save the file.  I'm pretty sure from the values I would have to use under RGB that those values would get changed when going back and saving as a gif like in [How to CREATE a transparent gif (or png) with PIL (python-imaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376359/how-to-create-a-transparent-gif-or-png-with-pil-python-imaging).  In my program the values CAN'T change.

Comment: can you show the error? docs say this Image.new("RGB", (512, 512), "white") so it shouldn't expect an int there. note color was added after 1.1.4 mentioned in docs too

Comment: Just in case this is helpful to you, or of interest.. http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/making-animated-gifs-from-video-files-with-python/

Comment: It says TypeError: an integer is needed.  I couldn't figure it out either.

Comment: First, you should probably use Pillow instead of PIL.  Second, the color argument appears to default to 0, meaning black, so you might try taking the default.

Comment: Why does it not bother when trying to create a RGB/RGBA image.  It creates that just fine.  I only run into trouble when I try 'P'.  Gee, I...keep learning.  I thought PIL and Pillow were one and the same thing.  OOPS:)