# Create a PNG and make it transparent

Tags: python, png

I'm trying to dynamically create a PNG (code is working) and make it transparent (code is not working on the color white).

I can create the PNG, but making it transparent isn't working.

Code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os

def text_on_img(filename='01.png', text="Hello", size=12):
    "Draw a text on an Image, saves it, show it"
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 52)
    # create image
    image = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(150, 75), color="white")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    # draw text
    draw.text((10, 10), text, font=fnt, fill=(0, 0, 0))
    newData = []
    newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))

    image.save(filename)
```

Comment: You need your image mode to be `"RGBA"`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8377135/2280890)

Comment: I saw this. This code does not work either.

Comment: Change `color="white"` to `color=(255, 255, 255, desired_opacity_level)`.

Comment: No, that has no effect on it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal example that creates the image in [RGBA](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes) mode and sets the background to be transparent.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
fnt = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 52)
img = Image.new(mode="RGBA", size=(150, 75), color=(255, 255, 255, 127))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((10, 10), "Hello", font=fnt, fill=(0, 0, 0))
img.save("test.png", "PNG")
```

This creates the following image:

[image: Hello, fully transparent background]

Changing the alpha to 127 (50%) results in the following image being created:

[image: Hello, 50% Opacity]

Comment: That’s it! You nailed it. Thanks!