# What algorithm is behind the Gimp's "Color to Alpha" feature?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, raster-graphics

For those who aren't familiar with the Gimp's "Color to Alpha" feature yet, here is the page on it from the Gimp's documentation: [Color to Alpha](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-colortoalpha.html). It does a really good job, and I wonder much how exactly Gimp does it in terms of color manipulation, whichever color space the colors might be in. Thanks a bunch for any hints.

**EDIT 1:** Generating transparency information for a pixel based on its similarity to the key color (the one you select in the "Color to Alpha" dialog), like some folk suggested before removing his answer for some reason, would sound like a good insight, but I suppose it's more intricate than that. Let's assume we estimate color similarity in the unit range from 0.0 to 1.0 and we've got a pixel whose color is, for example, 0.4 similar to, say, the color of white (like you would have selected white in the "Color to Alpha" dialog) and therefore the pixel gets an alpha value of 0.6, then how would you alter the pixel's actual color to compensate the loose of brightness/luminosity/saturation when the resulting pixel is displayed against a white background with the alpha of 0.6?

**EDIT 2:** Actually an update: The sub-question related to the first edit has been answered in [How to change the alpha of a pixel without changing the resulting color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282714/how-to-change-the-alpha-of-a-pixel-without-changing-the-resulting-color) but it's probably not the full story because what is going on in the Gimp's source for the "Color to Alpha" feature is not that simple and seems to be based on a specific algorithm rather than a formula.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282714/how-to-change-the-alpha-of-a-pixel-without-changing-the-resulting-color

Comment: @MarkRansom I know that the question you posted a link to is related as the one who asked that question was me! :) And even though your formula can achieve the effect of this Gimp's feature, the mystery still holds as the complexity of what I saw in the Gimp's sources is higher than in the formula of yours.

Comment: @MarkRansom Continuing: But your approach appears to be more flexible than Gimp's since, with the solution for a rewritten system of equations, one can "cut" an image out of a background of one color and lay it over a background of another color, and the image would still look the same. So I guess there is no much point in this question anymore, so I'm gonna register this question for deletion if no one doesn't mind.

Comment: I didn't even notice the other one was your question! This one is tougher, because you have an additional unknown - the maximum alpha value capable of retaining the output color. It's an interesting problem, I just haven't had time to work it yet. I wouldn't delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to come up with a mechanism for comparing the similarity of colors. There are a variety of color spaces in which you can do this. RGB is often not the best for this sort of thing. But you could use HSV, YCbCr, or some other luma/chroma space. Often a distance in one of those spaces will give you a better answer than a Euclidean distance in RGB. Once you have a distance, you could divide that by the maximum distance to get a percentage. That percentage would be the inverse of the alpha you want to use, as one possibility.

If you want to know how the GIMP does it, you can look at the source. For example, [here's one recent code change](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/plug-ins/common/colortoalpha.c?id=bcd98991017f85aff90aee36451970d59edcb95d) to that plug-in.

Comment: Thanks, but I already saw the source and it wasn't sufficiently straightforward and was poorly documented. And what your are writing in the first part of your answer is already addressed in the edition to my question, which in simpler words means that it's not hard to estimate similarity between two colors, rather what to do with the color of a pixel whose alpha has changed from 1.0 to some other value, which, in fact, is not complicated either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282714/how-to-change-the-alpha-of-a-pixel-without-changing-the-resulting-color

Comment: You seem to know about GIMP. Could you be enough kind to answer me to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147244/gimp-colorization-technique) ?

Comment: It appears the question has been deleted, so I don't know what the actual question was. Sorry!

Answer (score 10):

I took a look at the source code, and the meat of it is the colortoalpha function.  The parameters *a1 to *a4 are the input/output red, green, blue and alpha, respectively, and c1 to c3 is the color to make alpha.

When you're combining two colors c1 and c2 with a specific alpha a (0 ≤ a ≤ 1), the result is

```
y = a * c1 + (1-a) * c2
```

Here we're doing the reverse operation:  We know the end result y and the background color c2, and want to figure out c1 and a.  Since this is an under-specified equation, there's an infinite amount of solutions.  However, the ranges 0 ≤ c1 ≤ 255 and 0 ≤ a ≤ 1 adds bounds to the solution.

The way the Gimp plugin works is that for each pixel it minimizes the alpha value (i.e. maximizes transparency).  Conversely, this means that for each resulting pixel that isn't completely transparent (i.e. was not exactly the background color), one of the RGB components is either 0 or 255.

This produces an image that when overlayed on top of the specified color will produce the original image (in absence of rounding errors) and has maximum transparency for each pixel.

It's worth noting that the whole process is done in the RGB color space, but could be performed in others as well, as long as the combining operation is done in the same color space.

Answer (score 5):

I implemented this filter into my editor [www.Photopea.com](//www.Photopea.com) under Filter - Other - Color to Alpha. The results are 100% identical to GIMP. The algorithm is **extremely simple**.

The idea: a background color B was combined with a foreground color F using the transparency value A, to get a new color N:

```
N = A * F  +  (1 - A) * B;
```

You know N (the actual color in the image) and B (the parameter of the filter), and you want to recover the foreground color F and its transparency A.

Do it like this:

```
A = max( abs(N.r - B.r), abs(N.g - B.g), abs(N.b - B.b)  )
```

Now, you know N, B, A. Just use the formula above to compute the F.

Comment: Implemented it in unity, works like a charm !
float computeAlphaFromColorFilter(float3 color, float3 filter)
{
    return max(max(abs(color.r - filter.r), abs(color.g - filter.g)), abs(color.b - filter.b));
}
float alpha = computeAlphaFromColorFilter(col.xyz, _ColorFilter.xyz);
float3 finalColor = (col.xyz - (1. - alpha) * _ColorFilter.xyz)/alpha;
return float4(finalColor, alpha);

Answer (score 3):

So I looked into [GIMP source code](https://git.gnome.org//browse/gimp/tree/plug-ins/common/colortoalpha.c?id=bcd98991017f85aff90aee36451970d59edcb95d)... ew! I made it generic and readable.
Still quite fast though.
For math explanation see [Sampo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14915403/126537).
Here's C# implementation (easy convertible to C / C++):

```
static class PixelShaders {

    /// <summary>
    /// Generic color space color to alpha.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pA">Pixel alpha.</param>
    /// <param name="p1">Pixel 1st channel.</param>
    /// <param name="p2">Pixel 2nd channel.</param>
    /// <param name="p3">Pixel 3rd channel.</param>
    /// <param name="r1">Reference 1st channel.</param>
    /// <param name="r2">Reference 2nd channel.</param>
    /// <param name="r3">Reference 3rd channel.</param>
    /// <param name="mA">Maximum alpha value.</param>
    /// <param name="mX">Maximum channel value.</param>
    static void GColorToAlpha(ref double pA, ref double p1, ref double p2, ref double p3, double r1, double r2, double r3, double mA = 1.0, double mX = 1.0) {
        double aA, a1, a2, a3;
        // a1 calculation: minimal alpha giving r1 from p1
        if (p1 > r1) a1 = mA * (p1 - r1) / (mX - r1);
        else if (p1 < r1) a1 = mA * (r1 - p1) / r1;
        else a1 = 0.0;
        // a2 calculation: minimal alpha giving r2 from p2
        if (p2 > r2) a2 = mA * (p2 - r2) / (mX - r2);
        else if (p2 < r2) a2 = mA * (r2 - p2) / r2;
        else a2 = 0.0;
        // a3 calculation: minimal alpha giving r3 from p3
        if (p3 > r3) a3 = mA * (p3 - r3) / (mX - r3);
        else if (p3 < r3) a3 = mA * (r3 - p3) / r3;
        else a3 = 0.0;
        // aA calculation: max(a1, a2, a3)
        aA = a1;
        if (a2 > aA) aA = a2;
        if (a3 > aA) aA = a3;
        // apply aA to pixel:
        if (aA >= mA / mX) {
            pA = aA * pA / mA;
            p1 = mA * (p1 - r1) / aA + r1;
            p2 = mA * (p2 - r2) / aA + r2;
            p3 = mA * (p3 - r3) / aA + r3;
        } else {
            pA = 0;
            p1 = 0;
            p2 = 0;
            p3 = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

GIMP's implementation ([here](https://git.gnome.org//browse/gimp/tree/plug-ins/common/colortoalpha.c?id=bcd98991017f85aff90aee36451970d59edcb95d)) uses RGB color space, uses alpha value as `float` with 0 to 1 range, and R, G, B as `float` from 0 to 255.

RGB implementation fails spectacularly when image has JPEG artifacts, because they mean insignificant perceivable color deviations, but quite significant absolute R, G, B deviations. Using LAB colorspace should do the trick for the case.

If you're looking just to remove solid background from the image, color to alpha algorithm is not an optimal option. I got nice results when calculated colorspace distance for each pixel using LAB colorspace. The calculated distance was then applied to alpha channel of the original image. Main difference between this and color to alpha is the hue of the pixels would not be changed. Background remove just sets alpha (opacity) to colorspace difference. It works well if background color does not occur in foreground image. If it does either the background cannot be removed, or BFS algorithm must be used to walk the outer pixels only (something like using magic wand selection in GIMP, then removing the selection).

Background cannot be removed if the foreground image has both holes and pixels in color similar to background color. Such images require some manual processing.

Comment: I'havn't tested it yet, but already +1 for your work ;) I need the algo to apply it on svg images, I havn't found a solution to do it there ...

Comment: I wonder why it could be relevant with the vector graphics. BTW, now as I look at it I wonder what do `mA` and `mX` parameters mean. It lacks RGB to LAB color space conversions. If someone's interested in removing solid backgrounds from raster images I have some working code in C# implementing all I wrote here (LAB color space and BFS algo to leave object intact while removing the background). Just ask another question, because it's more than just mere "color to alpha" effect. I would call it intelligent background removal. Good for "green screen" pictures.

Comment: This works perfectly! In my case I was working with values from 0 - 255 so I set mA and mX to 255. As far as I can tell it exactly matches Gimp's result. I normally use colour-to-alpha in Gimp to create transparent overlay images for product previews on our website. This technique works great for keeping the shading and texture while allowing the customer's image to show through. Now I can finally do it in bulk with a NodeJS script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I translated the colortoalpha method from gimp to C# the best I could. The problem is RGBA values are taken as bytes for each channel in a library like [ImageSharp](http://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp). Some of the conversions are losing data during conversion but I tried my best to retain as much as I could. This uses ImageSharp for image mutation. ImageSharp is fully managed so it will work across platforms. Its also fast. This entire methods runs in around ~10ms (less than 10ms).

Here is the code for C# implementation:

```
public static unsafe void ColorToAlpha(this Image<Rgba32> image, Rgba32 color)
    {
        double alpha1, alpha2, alpha3, alpha4;
        double* a1, a2, a3, a4;

        a1 = &alpha1;
        a2 = &alpha2;
        a3 = &alpha3;
        a4 = &alpha4;

        for (int j = 0; j < image.Height; j++)
        {
            var span = image.GetPixelRowSpan(j);

            for (int i = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
            {
                ref Rgba32 pixel = ref span[i];

                // Don't know what this is for
                // *a4 = pixel.A;

                if (pixel.R > color.R)
                    *a1 = (pixel.R - color.R) / (255.0 - color.R);
                else if (pixel.R < color.R)
                    *a1 = (color.R - pixel.R) / color.R;
                else
                    *a1 = 0.0;

                if (pixel.G > color.G)
                    *a2 = (pixel.G - color.G) / (255.0 - color.G);
                else if (pixel.G < color.G)
                    *a2 = (color.G - pixel.G) / color.G;
                else
                    *a2 = 0.0;

                if (pixel.B > color.B)
                    *a3 = (pixel.B - color.B) / (255.0 - color.B);
                else if (pixel.B < color.B)
                    *a3 = (color.B - pixel.B) / color.B;
                else
                    *a3 = 0.0;

                if (*a1 > *a2)
                    *a4 = *a1 > *a3 ? *a1 * 255.0 : *a3 * 255.0;
                else
                    *a4 = *a2 > *a3 ? *a2 * 255.0 : *a3 * 255.0;

                if (*a4 < 1.0)
                    return;

                pixel.R = (byte)Math.Truncate((255.0 * (*a1 - color.R) / *a4 + color.R));
                pixel.G = (byte)Math.Truncate((255.0 * (*a2 - color.G) / *a4 + color.G));
                pixel.B = (byte)Math.Truncate((255.0 * (*a3 - color.B) / *a4 + color.B));

                pixel.A = (byte)Math.Truncate(*a4);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and implemented the `colortoalpha` in Python, so that I can easily script batch operations. It seems to match GIMP output perfectly!

```
import PIL.Image
import numpy as np

# Color to make transparent.
BG_COLOR_RGB = [255, 255, 255] # white

# 8 bits for every channel including alpha: 24-bit RGB input, 32-bit RGBA output
MAX_CHANNEL = 255
MAX_ALPHA = 255

# Open file and convert the data to NumPy
input_image = PIL.Image.open('input.jpg')
input = np.asarray(input_image)
bg_color = np.array(BG_COLOR_RGB, dtype=np.uint8)

# Inversing the formula: Img = alpha * Fg + (1-alpha) * Bg
alpha_per_channel = (0
                    + np.greater(input, bg_color)
                    * np.divide(input - bg_color, MAX_CHANNEL - bg_color,
                                where=np.greater(MAX_CHANNEL - bg_color, 0))
                    + np.less(input, bg_color)
                    * np.divide(bg_color - input, bg_color,
                                where=np.greater(bg_color,0)))
alpha = np.amax(alpha_per_channel, axis=2, keepdims=True)
foreground = np.divide(input - (1-alpha) * bg_color, alpha,
                       where=np.greater(alpha, 1e-4))

# Output has 4 channels (RGBA)
output = np.zeros([input.shape[0],input.shape[1],4], dtype=np.uint8)
# Set RGB channels
output[:, :, 0:3] = foreground
# Set alpha channel
output[:, :, 3:4] = alpha * MAX_ALPHA

# Save the file preserving DPI settings
PIL.Image.fromarray(output).save('output.png', dpi=input_image.info.get('dpi'))
```

You can find the full source code here: https://github.com/unicilindro/color2alpha/blob/main/color2alpha.py