# Removing background from product images

Tags: python, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a site on which you can upload product images. I'd like to be able to have users create collages of images - similar to how they do this on polyvore.com.

To make the images most useful, I'd like to remove the white background from arround the image, for instance, so that clothes look like just the clothes without the white background behind them. Is there a library, preferably for Python or Javascript, that could do this?

Also, does anyone have a sense as to what Polyvore is using to remove these images? I found a blog post here about the process, which looks as if users were at one point directing their image processing software manually: http://blog.polyvore.com/2009/10/introducing-custom-background-tool.html

I've seen http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php, is this the appropriate tool or is there another, better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the clothes aren't white.
check out this post for the answer.
[Using PIL to make all white pixels transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765736/using-pil-to-make-all-white-pixels-transparent)