# Compressing PNG images using PIL

Tags: png, python-imaging-library

I am having problem with increasing opacity to the image. My original image is of 230 KB
[image]

after i resize the image using the code:

```
Method 1:  imh=imgg.resize((1000,500),Image.ANTIALIAS) #filesize is 558 KB
Method 2:  imh=imgg.resize((1000,500),Image.ANTIALIAS)
           im2 = imh.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE) #filesize is 170KB
```

Now i am adding transparency of the image by using this code:

```
def reduce_opacity(im, opacity,pathname):
    assert opacity >= 0 and opacity <= 1
    if im.mode != 'RGBA':
        im = im.convert('RGBA')
    else:
        im = im.copy()
    alpha = im.split()[3]
    alpha = ImageEnhance.Brightness(alpha).enhance(opacity)
    im.putalpha(alpha)
    jj=<pathname>
    im.save(jj)
    return im
```

Method 1: filesize is 598 KB
Method 2: filesize is 383 KB

So the best code i got till now is

```
imh=imgg.resize((1000,500),Image.ANTIALIAS)
im2 = imh.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)
reduce_opacity(im2,0.5,name)
```

which gives me a file size of 383KB. To add opacity it has to be opened in RGBA mode which increase the file size from 170 KB to 383 KB.I am not satisfied with this, i need to reduce the size more, it there any way that i can achieve that, not compromising the quality to a great extent?

Comment: *None* of the compression methods in the PNG standard "compromise the quality". Use a tool such as `pngcrush`. OT: for what purpose are you 'adding transparency', to an image that does not require it?

Comment: @Jongware I need to write text on the image, so either i blur the image or add transparency to it.