# How to do transparent color inside the boundry in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, opacity

I have the images of brain tumor detection I want to do the transparent color inside the boundary of detection in python.

Transparent color will be same as the boundary color (122, 160, 255) with low opacity.

[Image of Brain Tumor Detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0pMX.png)

Expected Output:
[Expected Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm2ev.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python PIL 0.5 opacity, transparency, alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731035/python-pil-0-5-opacity-transparency-alpha)

Comment: Hey, you didnt add any code you tried, please edit your issue and add the code you tried to run so we can help you to debug the problem better

Comment: How can rgb(122,160,255) be transparent? It doesn't have an alpha channel, i.e. it isn't RGBA.

Comment: Yes I want to convert that color to alpha

Comment: That doesn’t make much sense to me, sorry. Can you click [edit] and add an image of your expected output please? Even a mocked up version is fine.

Comment: How is your boundary stored? Do you have a list of the boundary pixels? Or a black image with the boundary pixels in white? Or what?

Comment: I have black image with the boundary pixels in white.

Comment: Ok, that image belongs in your question then please.

Comment: Did you try my answer at all? How did you get on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way of doing this:

- load boundary image in greyscale and threshold
- find approximate centre of tumour
- flood-fill tumour interior with value=64, leaving boundary=255
- create a peachy overlay same size as original
- push the greyscale into the peachy overlay as alpha layer
- paste the overlay onto original

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Open boundary image and ensure greyscale
im = Image.open('boundary.png').convert('L')

# Get the bounding box so we can guesstimate its centre for flood-filling
bbox = im.getbbox()
cx = int((bbox[0]+bbox[1])/2)
cy = int((bbox[2]+bbox[3])/2)
print(f'DEBUG: cx={cx}, cy={cy}')

# Threshold the boundary image to pure black and white
thresh = im.point(lambda p: 255 if p>128 else 0)

# Flood-fill with 64 starting from the centre and proceeding to a pure white boundary border
ImageDraw.floodfill(thresh, (cx,cy), 64, border=255)
thresh.save('DEBUG-flood-filled.png')

# Open the original image
scan = Image.open('a0pMX.png')

# Create a peachy overlay, then push in the alpha layer
overlay = Image.new('RGB', scan.size, 'rgb(255,160,122)')
overlay.putalpha(thresh)
overlay.save('DEBUG-overlay.png')

# Paste the overlay onto the scan
scan.paste(overlay, mask=overlay)
scan.save('result.png')
```

Here are the intermediate images:

DEBUG-flood-filled.png

[image]

DEBUG-overlay.png

[image]

result.png

[image]