# Making background of a png picture transparent on a Frame in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a png picture which I show on a Frame as follows:

```
self.aaa = PhotoImage(file="some.png")
self.lbl1 = Label(self, image=self.aaa)
self.lbl1.pack()
```

The background of the picture is white and the background the Frame is darker. Can I somehow make the background of the Picture transparent without editing the picture, doesn't Tkinter allow that?

Comment: To use `PhotoImage` you had to use `PIL` which has many functions to edit images. Doc: [PIL/pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/)

Comment: @furas -- on the fly? it'd be ok for me, but permanently -- not.

Comment: if you don't use `save()` then it will be temporary - only in memory

Comment: @furas, could you show me an example?

Comment: [Using PIL to make all white pixels transparent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765736/using-pil-to-make-all-white-pixels-transparent)