# how to create a transparent mask instead of white color using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm using the following code to create mask with the white color. But when I extract it, I want it to be transparent. How can I do it?

```
 mask = cv2.ellipse(mask, center=(cX, cY), axes=(axesX, axesY), angle=0, startAngle=0, endAngle=360,
                       color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=-1)

inside = np.bitwise_and(image, mask)
outside = np.bitwise_and(image, ~mask)
```

http://answers.opencv.org/question/25523/extract-an-ellipse-form-from-an-image-instead-of-drawing-it-inside/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want the extracted image to be transparent? Also, post your image as an example.

Comment: Use **dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.7,inside,0.3,0)** Where **img1=np.zeros_like(inside)**.

Comment: @Zindarod It's similar to any product image on e-commerce website with white background mostly. It can also be black in some cases. You can pick any product image from amazon

Comment: @I.Newton it's not working

Comment: It would be better if you add your images as to exactly what you want.
 [Check this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html)

Comment: @I.Newton I've updated the image. I need the image without white color. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but if you are saying you need the white portion to be image or the opposite, you need to do operations like inverting the mask and adding to the image or adding their weighted sum etc depending on what the expected output is. The link i gave above shows an example.

Comment: @I.Newton I found the answer. I'm using pillow for Transparency+Mask : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765736/using-pil-to-make-all-white-pixels-transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by using the following code for Tranparency+Mask

[Using PIL to make all white pixels transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765736/using-pil-to-make-all-white-pixels-transparent)