# How can I make white background transparent with the image crate?

Tags: image, rust, rgba

Here's a minimal code sample that should convert `rgb` to `rgba` image (*goal*: make white background transparent):

````
extern crate image;

fn main() {
    // ```open``` returns a `DynamicImage` on success.
    let img = image::open("image_with_white_background.png").unwrap();

    // Should make white background transparent
    // Found a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765736/using-pil-to-make-all-white-pixels-transparent
    // Is there a nice method for that loop (see the answer to the question above)?
    let img = img.to_rgba();

    img.save("image_with_transparent_background.png").unwrap();
}
````

It don't really work though, there's still white background in `image_with_transparent_background.png`.

Here's the image I work with:

[image: picture]

Update: this piece of code works, but I wonder if there's something more elegant (e.g., can I reuse existing library call instead):

```
fn main() {
    let img = image::open("image_with_white_background.png").unwrap();


    let mut img = img.to_rgba();
    for p in img.pixels_mut() {
        if p[0] == 255 && p[1] == 255 && p[2] == 255 {
            p[3] = 0;
        }
    }

    img.save("image_with_transparent_background.png").unwrap();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not work". A proper description would be good. Is an error emitted? Does the result does not look like what you want? How does it differ?

Comment: @hellow the result still have a white background which is not I want.

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why would you expect it to be transparent now? The color white is still white. You haven't changed anything. You have to modify white to transparent somehow

Comment: @hellow I think that's exactly what I want actually.

Comment: Imo, you need to take a look at this [topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3mhf0y/piston_question_how_can_i_change_the_color_of_an/) Since you did not change the color itself, even though you change rgb to rgba, it does not work as you wanted.

Comment: @AkinerAlkan tbh I'm still confused a bit, I thought it should be pretty simple (e.g., worst case is to iterate over all pixels, if pixel = (255, 255, 255) then set it's transparency to 0 (all others have 1). I thought there's a special method for this loop operation.
E.g. look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765736/using-pil-to-make-all-white-pixels-transparent

Comment: @H.Desane In your reference question, After conversion to the rgba, there is a loop that makes the conversion process. So as similar you need to add this implementation to your code as well I guess.

Comment: A little bit off-topic, but this kind of image would gain to be in svg.